# has_and_belongs_to_many relation not working on new app creation on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am updating my Ruby from version 2.3 to 2.4 and using Rails 5, creating a new app with mysql databases.

```
rails new myapp1 -d mysql
```

Then I create 2 models like Users and Roles

```
rails g model Users username:string
rails g model Roles rolename:string
```

After that I create a migration for connecting models

```
rails g migration CreateRolesUsers users:references roles:references
```

Then I define the relationship on models as follow

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many   :roles
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many   :users
end
```

Finally, I open the rails console and run the following command

```
@user = User.new(:username => "Nifras")
@role = Role.new(:rolename => "admin")

@role.save

@user.roles << @roles
```

The above last line produce the following error:

```
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'user_id' for User::HABTM_Roles.
```

But my relationship table have the user_id it self. Where am I wrong and how to overcome this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is incorrect because it uses the plural.

```
rails g migration CreateRolesUsers users:references roles:references
```

Better would be

```
rails g migration CreateRolesUsers user:references role:references
```

Slightly more elegant

```
rails generate migration CreateJoinTableRoleUser role user
```

So, basically, do a `rake db:rollback`, delete the last migration in `db/migration`, and then use the second or third line above to generate the correct migration.   Alternatively, after roll back you can just edit the migration to change "users" and "roles" to "user" and "role".